# Verilog timing and clocking - input and output issues

Tags: input, verilog, simulation, clock

I have written this code in verilog and I have a problem with my code! 
What I want to do is to give as input the numbers 0 - 127 , so they can be written in mem and then to read them and see the output. I have set the clock to change every 5 from 0 to 1, which is happening, according to the results. But the numbers are being witten more than once in the memory. 
How can I fix this, in order the numbers will be written only once ? Could it be a timing-clocking problem ?

At the beginning the output data is 0, because I need to write the data first and then read them.

Also, I would like to know what I need to change so that when the last position of the memory is filled with the number 127, my program will understand that no other position of the memory is left empty!!
I am running the code in EDA Playground.

```
module process_data(
  input wire [63:0] DATA_IN ,  //input data 
  input QUE_Mode,              //fifo or filo 
  //input wire [6:0] AdrR ,    //pointers for read, write
  //input wire [6:0] AdrW,  
  input R_W ,
  input Cen,  
  input clk,
  input reset, 
  output reg [63:0]Reg_Data_Out,  //output data
  output reg Que_Full,            //state of the queue
  output reg Que_Last, 
  output reg Que_Empty);

  integer i;
  reg [63:0] Memory [0:127];      //array 
  reg [6:0] AdrW;
  reg [6:0] AdrR;

  initial begin        //initialization 
   Que_Full= 1'b0;     //when  Que_Full = 1'b0, the queue is not full 
   Que_Last = 1'b0;    //when  Que_Last = 1'b0, this is not the last item of the list that can be added to 
   Que_Empty = 1'b0;   //when Que_Empty = 1'b0, the queue is empty.
   AdrR=7'b0000_000;
   AdrW=7'b0000_000;

   i=0;   
    repeat (128)        //initialization of memory 
    begin
        Memory[i]=64'd1;    //64 bits/ position , 127 positions 
        i=i+1;
    end
   end 

  always @* begin
    $display("AdrR=%d",AdrR);
    $display("AdrW=%d",AdrW);

  end 

  always @(negedge(clk))
  begin
    if(Cen == 1'b1) begin                        // cen = chip enabled , when 1=> chip is enabled => circuit works
    case (R_W)   
      1'b1:
         begin
           if(Que_Empty == 1'b1 )begin           //check if queue not empty
                                                 // Return the value from the FIFO  foun at the read address
              Reg_Data_Out <= Memory[AdrR];      // (read)  out put memory context          
              AdrR<=AdrR+7'b0000_001;            //assign  AdrR [6:0] <= AdrR [6:0] +7'b0000_001;   
           end 
         end 

      1'b0:
        begin 
          if( Que_Full == 1'b0  )begin               //check if queue not full 
            if(AdrW >= 7'b0000_000) begin
              Memory[AdrW] <= DATA_IN ;              // write input to memory , On any write -> update the memory
              AdrW <= AdrW+7'b0000_001;              //non blocking statements to avoid race conditions 
              Que_Empty = 1'b1;                      //when Que_Empty = 1'b1, the queue is NOT empty

              if(AdrW==7'b1111_111)begin  
                                                     //AdrW <= 7'b0000_000;
                 Que_Full= 1'b1;                     //when  Que_Full = 1'b1, the queue IS full 
                 Que_Last = 1'b1;                    //when  Que_Last = 1'b0, this IS the last item of the list that can be added to 
              end 
            end
          end 
        end 

      default:
        Reg_Data_Out = 64'bxxxxxxxx;  
    endcase

    end
  end 
endmodule 


module clock(output reg clk);
  initial
  clk=1'b0;
  always
  #5 clk=~clk;
endmodule


module TOP();
  parameter ENDTIME=40000;  

  reg [63:0] inputdata1;  // is an 63-bit "register", or variable  
  wire [6:0] AddressR,AddressW;

  reg cen, R_W, reset;  //clk=1'b0  , 
  reg QUE_Mode;

  wire [63:0] Data_Out;

  integer count;
  integer i;

  wire Que_Full, Que_Last, Que_Empty;

  wire clk;

  //call module for data I/O 
  process_data process_data(
    inputdata1,
    QUE_Mode,
    //AddressR,
    //AddressW, 
    R_W ,
    cen, 
    clk, 
    reset,
    Data_Out, 
    Que_Full,
    Que_Last,
    Que_Empty);  //reset, Que_Full, Que_Last, Que_Empty do not do anything yet

  clock MyClock(clk);
  initial
  begin
    $dumpfile("ALU.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0);

    $display("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSIMULATION RESULT ");  
    $display("\t\ttime\tclk\t\t\tinputdata1\t\tData_Out\tQUE_Mode\t\tAddressR\t\tAddressW\t\tQue_Full\t\Que_Last\t\Que_Empty");
    $monitor($time, "\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d",clk,inputdata1,Data_Out,QUE_Mode,AddressR,AddressW,Que_Full,Que_Last,Que_Empty);


    cen=1'b1;   //chip enabled 
    count = 0;
    R_W = 1'b0;   //write
    QUE_Mode = 1'b0; // QUE_Mode = 1'b0 => FIFO MODE 
    i=0;

    //input    
    for (i = 0; i < 128; i = i + 1) begin   //input   
                R_W=1'b0;   //write
                inputdata1 = i;
                #20;
           end  

    #10 
    for (i = 0; i < 128; i = i + 1) begin //output   
                #20; 
                R_W=1'b1;   //read  => output
                #20;
           end  
    $display("-------------- THE SIMULATION FINISHED ------------");  
    $finish; 
   end

endmodule
```

RESULTS:

```
                            SIMULATION RESULT 
        time    clk         inputdata1      Data_Out    QUE_Mode        AddressR        AddressW         Que_Full   Que_Last    Que_Empty
AdrR=  0
AdrW=  0
AdrR=  0
AdrW=  1
                   0    0                      0                       x    0  z  z001
                   5    1                      0                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW=  2
                  10    0                      0                       x    0  z  z001
                  15    1                      0                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW=  3
                  20    0                      1                       x    0  z  z001
                  25    1                      1                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW=  4
                  30    0                      1                       x    0  z  z001
                  35    1                      1                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW=  5
                  40    0                      2                       x    0  z  z001
                  45    1                      2                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW=  6
                  50    0                      2                       x    0  z  z001
                  55    1                      2                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW=  7
                  60    0                      3                       x    0  z  z001
                  65    1                      3                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW=  8
                  70    0                      3                       x    0  z  z001
                  75    1                      3                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW=  9
                  80    0                      4                       x    0  z  z001
                  85    1                      4                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW= 10
                  90    0                      4                       x    0  z  z001
                  95    1                      4                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW= 11
                 100    0                      5                       x    0  z  z001
                 105    1                      5                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW= 12
                 110    0                      5                       x    0  z  z001
                 115    1                      5                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW= 13
                 120    0                      6                       x    0  z  z001
                 125    1                      6                       x    0  z  z001
AdrR=  0
AdrW= 14
                 130    0                      6                       x    0  z  z001
                 135    1                      6                       x    0  z  z001
......................


AdrR=121
AdrW=  0
                7630    0                    127                      60    0  z  z111
                7635    1                    127                      60    0  z  z111
AdrR=122
AdrW=  0
                7640    0                    127                      60    0  z  z111
                7645    1                    127                      60    0  z  z111
AdrR=123
AdrW=  0
                7650    0                    127                      61    0  z  z111
                7655    1                    127                      61    0  z  z111
AdrR=124
AdrW=  0
                7660    0                    127                      61    0  z  z111
                7665    1                    127                      61    0  z  z111
AdrR=125
AdrW=  0
                7670    0                    127                      62    0  z  z111
                7675    1                    127                      62    0  z  z111
AdrR=126
AdrW=  0
                7680    0                    127                      62    0  z  z111
                7685    1                    127                      62    0  z  z111
-------------- THE SIMULATION FINISHED ------------
AdrR=127
                7690    0                    127                      63    0  z  z111
Done
```

Comment: Seeing the first lines of the results, where addrw=1 and addrw=2(write pointer), the input is 0 0 and then 0 0 !!!! The number : 0 is being given 4 times as input,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your input data twice as quickly.  Change `#20` to `#10`:

```
    //input    
    for (i = 0; i < 128; i = i + 1) begin   //input   
                R_W=1'b0;   //write
                inputdata1 = i;
//                #20;
                #10;
           end
```

This will write 0 to address 0, 1 to address 1, ... 127 to address 127.

---

The 1st write is to address 0 at time=0.  However, there is a race condition between the `initial` and `always` blocks which could result in different behavior on different simulators.

---

The log file shows output on every edge of `clk`, both posedge and negedge, because you have `clk` in the `$monitor` statement. But, the data is only changing once per clock period (as desired).